# unable to get result from native voice recorder using intent

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to start native record activity, the voice recorder shows up and when it save the clip, my application shows error. i am using htc desire and htc wildfire and also testing on emulator,

```
           Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, GET_AUDIO);


       @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      switch (requestCode) {
   case GET_AUDIO:
    Log.i(TAG, data.getDataString());
    break;
 }
}
```

**my Logcat Message**

```
09-18 15:18:35.015: ERROR/ContentService(98): Content Service Crash
09-18 15:18:35.015: ERROR/ContentService(98): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 15:18:35.015: ERROR/ContentService(98):     at android.content.ContentService.notifyChange(ContentService.java:166)
09-18 15:18:35.015: ERROR/ContentService(98):     at android.content.IContentService$Stub.onTransact(IContentService.java:91)
09-18 15:18:35.015: ERROR/ContentService(98):     at android.content.ContentService.onTransact(ContentService.java:83)
09-18 15:18:35.015: ERROR/ContentService(98):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
09-18 15:18:35.015: ERROR/ContentService(98):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)



09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/audio/media/9 }} to activity {ChatActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3712)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3754)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2162)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)




09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1253)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.notifyChange(IContentService.java:458)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:850)
09-18 15:18:35.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4477):     at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:836)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like null pointer exception in your onActivityResult.

You must expect that data may be null, and also check for resultCode. Don't call methods on data blindly without checking what's returned.

Comment: well i need to get the path of the file  that voice recorder just recorded.

Comment: i did record the voice so it should return me the file path, I am sure the file path cannot be null becuase it just stored the file on sd card and i can see that.